# How to dismiss a stack of UIViewControllers to a certain Root ViewController?

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

Some `RootViewController` presents a `ParentViewController` which than presents a `ChildViewController`.

How can I dissmiss the `ChildViewController` **animated** directly to the `RootViewController` whithout showing the `ParentViewController` again?

---

**In Detail**

- Assume some  presents the `ParentViewController` which lets the user enter some credentials to login to some user account.
- Once the connection is established the `ParentViewController` presents the `ChildViewController` which shows connection / account details to the user
- When the user closes the `ChildViewController` it should be dismissed **animated** (slide down, etc.). But instead of returning to the `ParentViewController` the user should get back directly to the `RootViewController`

Of course it would be possible, that the `ParentViewController` does not present the `ChildViewController` itself but (somehow) tells the `RootViewController` to this. This way it would be no problem to directly return from the `ChildViewController` to the `RootViewController`. However, this is **NOT** what I am looking for, since the `RootViewController` should not know about the `ChildViewController` or even care if the `ParentViewController` presents other VCs.

I am looking for a solution where the `ParentViewController` controls whether itself is shown after the VC it presented is dismissed or its parent (= the root VC).

**Code:**

```
typealias CompletionBlock = () -> Void

class RootViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBAction func showParentVC(_ sender: Any) {
        let parentVC = ParentViewController()
        parentVC.completion = {
            self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        }

        present(parentVC, animated: true)
    }
}

class ParentViewController: UIViewController {
    var completion: CompletionBlock?

    @IBAction func showChild(_ sender: Any) {
        let childVC = ChildViewController()
        childVC.completion = {
            self.completion?()
        }

        present(childVC, animated: true)
    }
}

class ChildViewController: UIViewController {
    var completion: CompletionBlock?

    @IBAction func close(_ sender: Any) {
        completion?()
    }
}
```

Using this code does **NOT** solve the described problem. If `close` is called on the `ChildViewController` the `RootViewController` calls `self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)`. This way the `ChildViewController` animates away and the `ParentViewController` becomes visible. Then the `ParentViewController` animates away and the `RootViewController`becomes visible.

**How to skip the `ParentViewController` and directly show the `RootViewController` after animating away the `ChildViewController`?**

Comment: Your explanation conflicts with the documentation. Which says "If you present several view controllers in succession, thus building a stack of presented view controllers, calling this method on a view controller lower in the stack dismisses its immediate child view controller and all view controllers above that child on the stack. When this happens, only the top-most view is dismissed in an animated fashion; any intermediate view controllers are simply removed from the stack.

Comment: Link to the doc https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621505-dismiss

Comment: @ShreeramBhat Yes, I know this passage from the docs. However, this is not what I observe when I use the code I posted above... Is this a bug or are the docs outdated or incomplete (what would not be too unusual...)

Answer (score 2):

My recommendation is embed your RootViewController into a NavigationController (if you don't have it yet) and present both parent a child with

```
navigationController?.present(viewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
//instead of viewController.present(...)
```

And then youcan use this method from your childViewController

```
navigationController?.popToRootViewController(animated: true)
```

Comment: But what if `RootViewController` should not be in a `UINavigationControll` / should not have a navigation bar, etc.? The

Answer (score 1):

One approach would be to set the view's alpha to Zero when you present another VC onto the "stack" of presented VCs.

So, present the first modal VC from the "root" VC as normal. For each "child" that presents another VC, use:

```
present(vc, animated: true, completion: {
    self.view.alpha = 0.0
})
```

Now, when you call-back to the "root" VC to dismiss all the VCs, you won't see the partial / flash of the intermediate VC / VCs.

Here is a complete example to test. No `@IBOutlets` or `@IBActions` ... just start with a black view controller and assign its Custom Class to `MultiPresentDismissViewController`:

```
import UIKit

class MultiPresentDismissViewController: UIViewController {

    let theLabel: UILabel = {
        let v = UILabel()
        v.textAlignment = .center
        v.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 40)
        v.backgroundColor = .yellow
        v.text = "\"Root\" VC"
        return v
    }()

    let showAnotherButton: UIButton = {
        let v = UIButton()
        v.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 0.9, alpha: 1.0)
        v.setTitle("Present a VC", for: .normal)
        v.setTitleColor(.blue, for: .normal)
        v.setTitleColor(.cyan, for: .highlighted)
        return v
    }()

    let theStackView: UIStackView = {
        let v = UIStackView()
        v.axis = .vertical
        v.alignment = .fill
        v.distribution = .fill
        v.spacing = 32
        return v
    }()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        view.backgroundColor = .white

        [theLabel, showAnotherButton].forEach {
            theStackView.addArrangedSubview($0)
            $0.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
        }

        theStackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        view.addSubview(theStackView)

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            theStackView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor),
            theStackView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: 100.0),
            theStackView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor, multiplier: 0.8),
            ])

        showAnotherButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(presentAnotherVC), for: .touchUpInside)

    }

    @objc func presentAnotherVC() -> Void {
        let vc = AnotherViewController()
        vc.myID = 1
        present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

}

class AnotherViewController: UIViewController {

    let theLabel: UILabel = {
        let v = UILabel()
        v.textAlignment = .center
        v.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 100)
        v.backgroundColor = .yellow
        return v
    }()

    let showAnotherButton: UIButton = {
        let v = UIButton()
        v.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 0.9, alpha: 1.0)
        v.setTitle("Present Another VC", for: .normal)
        v.setTitleColor(.blue, for: .normal)
        v.setTitleColor(.cyan, for: .highlighted)
        return v
    }()

    let defaultDismissButton: UIButton = {
        let v = UIButton()
        v.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 0.9, alpha: 1.0)
        v.setTitle("Default Dismiss All", for: .normal)
        v.setTitleColor(.blue, for: .normal)
        v.setTitleColor(.cyan, for: .highlighted)
        return v
    }()

    let theStackView: UIStackView = {
        let v = UIStackView()
        v.axis = .vertical
        v.alignment = .fill
        v.distribution = .fill
        v.spacing = 20
        return v
    }()

    var myID: Int = 0

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        view.backgroundColor = .random()

        [theLabel, showAnotherButton, defaultDismissButton].forEach {
            theStackView.addArrangedSubview($0)
            $0.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
        }

        theStackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        view.addSubview(theStackView)

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            theStackView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor),
            theStackView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: 100.0),
            theStackView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor, multiplier: 0.8),
            ])

        theLabel.text = "\(myID)"

        showAnotherButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(presentAnotherVC), for: .touchUpInside)
        defaultDismissButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(defaultDismissAll), for: .touchUpInside)

    }

    @objc func presentAnotherVC() -> Void {
        let vc = AnotherViewController()
        vc.myID = myID + 1
        present(vc, animated: true, completion: {
            self.view.alpha = 0.0
        })
    }

    @objc func defaultDismissAll() -> Void {
        // walk up the "presenting" hierarchy to find the "root" VC
        var vc = self.presentingViewController
        while vc?.presentingViewController != nil {
            vc = vc?.presentingViewController
        }
        vc?.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

}

extension CGFloat {
    static func random() -> CGFloat {
        return CGFloat(arc4random()) / CGFloat(UInt32.max)
    }
}

extension UIColor {
    static func random() -> UIColor {
        return UIColor(red:   .random(),
                       green: .random(),
                       blue:  .random(),
                       alpha: 1.0)
    }
}
```

Comment: Sounds promising but does not work: One still sees a flash o the intermediate VC. Not the VCs view / content but a black screen.

Comment: @AndreiHerford - Hmmm.... I edited my answer to include a complete example. Give it a try?