# Swift 5 - Middle view controller briefly appearing - Should remove?

Tags: ios, swift

Setup:

Initial view controller A has a menu button that goes to VC B, which then has a button that goes to VC C.  On C, I have an exit button that takes me back to A.  In this transition, B briefly appears.  The two things I'm trying to figure out is:

1. How do I keep B from flashing on the screen?

and

2. Is B off the call stack and releasing the memory?

This is what I'm running to get rid of the C and go back to A:

```
 @IBAction func backButtonPressed(_ sender: Any) {
        self.view.window!.rootViewController?.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        //performSegue(withIdentifier: "exitToMainScreen", sender: self)
    }
```

Comment: Are these both presented (modal) view controllers?

Comment: @matt Yes, both are.

Comment: Searching shows there is quite a bit of discussion on this. Here is one approach to avoid seeing the "VC B" flash: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57994777/6257435

Comment: @DonMag the alpha trick did not work.  I executed it just before the performSegue i n VC B to VC C, but when I click exit on C, B still flashes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a work-around for this glitch.

In VC B, I encapsulated everything in a view attached to an outlet.  So when I perform the segue to VC C, I set the view's isHidden = true.  When the unwind from C to A occurs, the view in B is hidden and does not appear on the screen in transition.